# editor template return null value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created an editor template base on this article [ASP.NET MVC: Annotated for Input by Dino Esposito](https://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=1786)

Everything works fine until i press the submit button. I find out that my POST function return model is NULL, its like the model is not bind to the view. I have been trying all trick that I know and I found from the internet but I still can't fix it.

This is my controller

```
    // GET: /Asset/New

    public ActionResult New()
    {
        ViewBag.typeID = new SelectList(db.Ref_Asset_Types, "ID", "name");
        return View(new AssetViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult New(AssetViewModel vm) 
    // vm.asset should contain new value but currently return null
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Assets.Add(vm.asset);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.typeID = new SelectList(db.Ref_Asset_Types, "ID", "name", vm.asset.typeID);         
        return View("New", vm);
    }
```

this is my view

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("New","Asset","POST")) {
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
      @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

      @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.asset, "InputTemplate" )
```

// note : the code works if i don't use my own template ==> @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.asset)

```
      <div class="form-actions btn pull-right">
         @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-sm"})
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-sm" value="Index"> 
            Reset 
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            Tambah
        </button>          
      </div>
    }
```

and this is my InputTemplate

```
    @inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage 
    @if (Model == null) 
    { 
       <span>@ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText</span> 
    } 
    else 
    {        
       foreach (var prop in ViewData 
          .ModelMetadata 
          .Properties 
          .Where(pm => pm.ShowForDisplay && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm))) 
       { 
          if (prop.DisplayName != null) {   // only display prop not of ComplexType
          // note : using bootstrap for css styling
          <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
            <label class="col-xs-4 control-label text-right">
               <span style="color:red"> @(prop.IsRequired ? "*" : "")  </span>
               <span>@prop.GetDisplayName()</span>
            </label>

          <div class="col-xs-8">                      
            @if(prop.IsReadOnly) 
            { 
               <span class="readonly-field">@Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)</span> 
            } 
            else if (prop.TemplateHint == "DropDown")
            { 
               <span>@Html.DropDownList(prop.PropertyName,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewData[prop.PropertyName], new { @class = "form-control" })</span>
               <span>@Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName)</span>
            } 
            else
            {
               <div class="editor-field"> 
                 <span>@Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName, new { @class = "text-box single-line form-control" })</span> 
                 <span>@Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName, new { @class = "label-danger" } )</span> 
               </div>
            }                     
          </div>
         </div>

         } // if
       } // foreach
    }
```

This is my viewmodel

```
    using System;
    using SIGMA.Models;

    namespace SIGMA.ViewModels
    {

    public class AssetViewModel
    { 
       public AssetViewModel() 
       {
          asset = new Asset();
       }
       public Asset asset { get; set; }
    }   


    }
```

This is my model

```
    public class Asset
    {
      [Key]
      [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
      public int ID { get; set; }

      [DisplayName("No. Siri")]
      [StringLength(45)]
      public string serial_num { get; set; }

      [DisplayName("Model")]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Model perlu diisi!")]
      [StringLength(45)]
      public string model { get; set; }

      [DisplayName("Harga Seunit")]
      [RegularExpression(@"^\d{0,6}(\.\d{2})?$", ErrorMessage = "Sila gunakan format harga yang betul.")]
      public float? unit_cost { get; set; }

      [UIHint("DropDown")]
      [DisplayName("Jenis Aset")]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Jenis aset perlu dipilih!")]
      [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "Belum didaftar")]
      public int? typeID { get; set; }

      public virtual Ref_Asset_Type type { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What does the generated output from the editor template look like when you view the source? At a cursory glance I would suggest that the reflected property names do not match the model binding convention

Comment: Your `EditorTemplate` is rending controls for property `asset`. You have not shown this class but assuming it is typeof `Asset` and  contains a property `ID`,  the associated control will have `name="ID"`, but your POST method parameter is `AssetViewModel` which means the control must be `name="asset.ID"`. What are you trying to achieve with this code that can't be done using a standard `EditorTemplate`?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke - what i'm trying here is to create one template that can be use by any model. so i can maintain the same style in all my add and edit views. By the way I have try to send model instead of viewmodel but i cannot get to pass the model to my template. (this viewmodel follows suggestion from articles by Dino)

Comment: i've added the viewmodel and model for reference. @Brent Mannering - the source is actually to my eyes is the same as when i'm using the default template  => the input box will have id = asset_property_name and name = property_name

Comment: @bapak71, Is this the real code (why on earth have a view model if it only contains one property which is the domain model)? Inspect the html this is generating - are the `name` attributes on the controls `name="asset.ID"` or `name="ID"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys for the trouble.. i think i solve it.

My biggest mistake is using reserved word 'model' and 'type' as my property name. This some how cause problem to asp.net in interpreting my model using the user define editor template.

Once I change my property name - model to model_name and type to asset_type, i can see the my entry in my return model already.

Thanks to all

.... spends the whole day and night for this silly mistake but the lesson learn is worth it